# customized tableviewrow in titanium

Tags: android, titanium

i have created a tableview in which clicking on each tableviewrow(parent row) i get another tableviewrow(child row) append .In tableviewrow appended i am trying to create a two views inside appended tblviewrow,one view for buttons and other view for details for each buttons which should appear on clicking on each button.
my tried code is below

```
  var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
        //rightImage:"application-black.png"
        var apendedrwmainview = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor : "white",
            layout : "vertical"
        });
        var apendedrwsbviewfrst = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor : "white",
            layout : "horizontal"
        });
    apendedrwmainview.add(apendedrwsbviewfrst);

     var apendedrwsbviewsecnd = Ti.UI.createView({backgroundColor: "red", layout: "vertical", height: '50',width:'100'});
   var aLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
         text : 'APPLICATION',
         color : 'red',
         font : {
         fontSize : 15
         },

         top : 110,
         left : 80,
         textAlign : 'left'
         });

         // Add to the parent view.
         apendedrwsbviewsecnd.add(aLabel);   
      apendedrwmainview.add(apendedrwsbviewsecnd);
        row.add(apendedrwmainview);
        tableView.insertRowAfter(e.index, row);
        value1 = false;
        break;
    } else {
        tableView.deleteRow(e.index + 1);
        value1 = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

});

in this code i am getting  first view second view is not creating what mistake i have done please help me i am new to titanium

the row i am trying to append looks like this in below figure
[image]

this row should get append and removed when i click the parent row in tableview.

Comment: please provide more **clear** info about your issue.

Comment: @turtle i am appending row which looks as shown in fig,which contains 4 tabs

Comment: I think you are searching for term *accordion*, please check this [post](http://www.thewarpedcoder.net/2013/03/titanium-accordion-table-view-ios/)

Comment: @turtle i have made row to append and remove but prob is in appended row i have to create tab groups  and by clicking on each tab i should get different view in the same appended row

Comment: You can store data related to each tab in different array ( of tableViewRow ). Now when you click on a specific tab just change the data of the tableView using [setData()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-setData) method.